# Using Selenium Chrome Driver to search elemets by xpath is not working

Tags: selenium, xpath, cucumber, automated-tests

I am running my Cucumber Test using Selenium and using Chrome driver. I am trying to get a div element with xpath but it is not working.

It is the html element:

```
<div class="row" id="headerspacing"></div>
```

And it is my test code:

```
WebElement div = agent.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='headerspacing']"));
Assert.assertNotNull(div);
```

But I am getting an error message with the element:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='headerspacing']"}
```

### Update: new tab window

In the previous steps declared in my Cucumber tests Selenium hit a link (tag element **a**) and it step is opening a new tab windows. I thought Selenium was searching into that page and it is the problem: It was looking into the current page instead of new tab.

So maybe my question:

**How do I search or move my driver in order to do a search into the new open tab windows?**

Comment: Have you tried the xpath without the dot?

Comment: Check whether your `div` located inside an `iframe`

Comment: @AnassAhmed yes I did it and same result.

Comment: @Andersson it is inside of ```table > tbody >  tr > td > div```. I am testing and not the designer.

Comment: Does table located inside an `iframe`? :) Check if there an ancestor `<iframe>`. Use developer's console (`F12`) of your browser to check this info

Comment: @Andersson, no it is not inside of ```<iframe>```. I just told you that I am unable to re-design the page. For me the design if that is not pretty good but I need to test that element.

Comment: If you can show more piece of html, it will be helpful. Also, how did you define the Webelement agent?

Comment: The element has an id... why not just use `.findElementById()`? Are you sure that id is unique on the page? Have you tried adding a wait? You need to add a lot more details on what you have tried and what the results were.

Answer (score 0):

If the `div` is in a new window (tab), you must switch to that window before you can locate any elements on it.  So, before trying to find the element, you want to do:

`switchTo().window("windowName");`

Comment: Do I need to use a delay because it is not finding the new windows tab. I was using the new windows url and it was working but with the ```switchTo().window("windowName");``` it doesn't work.